# TIdNTLMAuthentication with something other than TIdHTTP

Tags: indy, delphi-xe5, sspi, ntlm-authentication

I am experimenting with Google RPC and managed to establish an encrypted connection. Now I would like to perform NTLM authentication on server. I know that I should use a pair of functions `InitializeSecurityContext` and `AcceptSecurityContext` for that.

I was intending to do it by myself, but then I found traces of these functions in Indy components, namely in `IdAuthenticationSSPI.pas` and `IdSSPI.pas`. After unsuccessful attempts to figure out what and how could I use for my task from Indy library, I started to look for examples in Internet, but all these examples work with `TIdHTTP` component.

Could I really use SSPI separately from Indy?

Comment: The `IdAuthentication...` units are designed for use with `TIdHTTP`.  The `IdSSPI` unit, on the other hand, is more of a standalone wrapper for Microsoft's SSPI API, so you should be able to use `IdSSPI` by itself for things other than HTTP. But there are no examples of using `IdSSPI`, as it was only ever intended to be used in Indy. Also, IIRC, `IdSSPI` is incomplete, there are some details used in `IdAuthenticationSSPI` that should/could be moved into `IdSSPI` to make it a more complete wrapper. But you can't use `IdSSPI` outside of Indy completely, because it depends on the `IdGlobal` unit.

Comment: Thank you. Then I'll do it by the hand.